# Find Numbers in a List Consisting of Strings and Convert them to Floats

Tags: python

I'm trying to do an exercise where I have a list:

```
list_1 = ['chocolate;1.20', 'book;5.50', 'hat;3.25']
```

And I have to make a second list out of it that looks like this:

```
list_2 = [['chocolate', 1.20], ['book', 5.50], ['hat', 3.25]]
```

In the second list the numbers have to be **floats** and **without the** **' '**

So far I've come up with this code:

```
for item in list_1:
    list_2.append(item.split(';'))
```

The output looks about right:

```
[['chocolate', '1.20'], ['book', '5.50'], ['hat', '3.25']]
```

But how do I convert those numbers into floats and remove the double quotes?

I tried:

```
for item in list_2:
    if(item.isdigit()):
        item = float(item)
```

Getting:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = ['chocolate;1.20', 'book;5.50', 'hat;3.25']
list_2 = [x.split(';') for x in list_1]
list_3 = [[x[0], float(x[1])] for x in list_2]
```

Comment: You can improve this, removing the interstitial assignment to `list_2`. `list_3 = [[y[0], float(y[1])] for x in list_1 for y in [x.split(';')]]`

Comment: I do not think that this is an improvement, since it gets kind of unreadable in my opinion.

Comment: It's opinion at this point really. Unless `list_2` is necessary elsewhere, they accomplish the same without creating an entire additional list.

Answer (score 1):

`item` is a list like `['chocolate', '1.20']`. You should be calling `isdigit()` on `item[1]`, not `item`. But `isdigit()` isn't true when the string contains `.`, so that won't work anyway.

Put the split string in a variable, then call `float()` on the second element.

```
for item in list_1:
    words = item.split(';')
    words[1] = float(words[1])
    list_2.append(words)
```

Comment: You may wish to limit the split to splitting at most one time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helpful for you.
But,I think using function is better than just using simple **for loop**
Just try it.

```
def list_map(string_val,float_val):
    return [string_val,float_val]

def string_spliter(list_1):
    string_form=[]
    float_form=[]
    
    for string in list_1:
        str_val,float_val=string.split(";")
        string_form.append(str_val)
        float_form.append(float_val)
    return string_form,float_form

list_1 = ['chocolate;1.20', 'book;5.50', 'hat;3.25']
    
string_form,float_form=string_spliter(list_1)
float_form=list(map(float,float_form))
output=list(map(list_map,string_form,float_form))

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a problem like this you can initialize two variables for the result of calling the split function and then append a list of both values and call the builtin `float` function on the second value.

```
array = []
for i in a_list:
    string, number = i.split(";")
    array.append([string, float(number)])

print(array)
```

Comment: `array` may be a misleading name, as the value is a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Your way of creating list_2 is fine. To then make your new list, you can use `final_list = [[i[0], float(i[1])] for i in list_2]`

You could also do it in the for loop like this:

```
for item in list_1:
  split_item = item.split(';')
  list_2.append([split_item[0], float(split_item[1])])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function map to convert each value.

```py
def modify_element(el): 
    name, value = el.split(';')
    return [name, float(value)]

list_1 = ['chocolate;1.20', 'book;5.50', 'hat;3.25']

result = list(map(modify_element, list_1))
```

Comment: As the operations on `list_1` are trivial, a list comprehension provides a Pythonic single line declarative option that should probably be used.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in two lines of code using list comprehensions.

```
list_1 = ['chocolate;1.20', 'book;5.50', 'hat;3.25']
list_2 = [[a, float(b)] for x in list_1 for a, b in [x.split(';', 1)]]
```

The second "dimension" to the list comprehension generates a list with a single sublist. This lets us essentially save the result of splitting each item and then bind those two items to `a` and `b` to make using them cleaner that having to specify indexes.

Note: by calling `split` with a second argument of `1` we ensure the string is only split at most once.